# Error 401 with IIS and Windows Authentication

Tags: authentication, iis

There is following authorization issue with IIS and windows authorization:

User A can access a specific website without problems.
Entering the URL in the browser, the site is opened without asking for credentials.

On the domain controller, i create a new user B cloning from user A.

If user B is entering the URL of the specific website, he will be asked for credentials for 3 times and access will be denied with error 401.

Any ideas or do you need more information?

Best regards

Comment: Can you check IIS log files to see which 401 user B hits? https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: In log files, some lines are ending with
- 401 3 0 5
- 401 3 0 2
- 401 3 0 3
- 401 3 0 1
I assume it is 401.3

Comment: read the article again please. It is an index page.

Comment: It seems to be using Windows Integrated, and User B does not have permissions to the underlying resource that is being requested (possibly a file, in which case it would be Windows permissons to that file.)  If the website is simply pointing to a Windows folder, it would be to whatever IIS considers the default web file is the folder, like 'index.html' for example.  Check the Windows permissions on that file and ANY included file on that page like images and external javascript files.